# How can I change the data-icon attribute via jQuery (bootstrap-iconpicker)?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with the bootstrap icon picker (http://victor-valencia.github.io/bootstrap-iconpicker/) and I want to change the default icon via jQuery by button click. Something is not working, and I cannot figure it out:

```js
$( "#click" ).click(function() {
  $('.icon').data('icon', 'glyphicon-bomb');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://victor-valencia.github.io/bootstrap-iconpicker/icon-fonts/elusive-icons-2.0.0/css/elusive-icons.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://victor-valencia.github.io/bootstrap-iconpicker/icon-fonts/font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://victor-valencia.github.io/bootstrap-iconpicker/bootstrap-iconpicker/css/bootstrap-iconpicker.min.css" />


<script src="http://victor-valencia.github.io/bootstrap-iconpicker/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://victor-valencia.github.io/bootstrap-iconpicker/bootstrap-3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://victor-valencia.github.io/bootstrap-iconpicker/bootstrap-iconpicker/js/iconset/iconset-glyphicon.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://victor-valencia.github.io/bootstrap-iconpicker/bootstrap-iconpicker/js/iconset/iconset-all.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://victor-valencia.github.io/bootstrap-iconpicker/bootstrap-iconpicker/js/bootstrap-iconpicker.js"></script>


<button class="icon btn btn-default" data-iconset="glyphicon" data-icon="glyphicon-camera" role="iconpicker"></button>

<div id="click">Click here to change the icon</div>
```

Comment: You say you want to select it but your code says you want to change it's data-icon attribute.  Which is the problem?

Comment: @winseybash I updated my question to be more clear

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're not specifying the `data-icon` properly.  `data` has to be included in the selector name.

See changed code below:

```js
$( "#click" ).click(function() {
  $('.icon').attr('data-icon', 'glyphicon-bomb');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://victor-valencia.github.io/bootstrap-iconpicker/icon-fonts/elusive-icons-2.0.0/css/elusive-icons.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://victor-valencia.github.io/bootstrap-iconpicker/icon-fonts/font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://victor-valencia.github.io/bootstrap-iconpicker/bootstrap-iconpicker/css/bootstrap-iconpicker.min.css" />


<script src="http://victor-valencia.github.io/bootstrap-iconpicker/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://victor-valencia.github.io/bootstrap-iconpicker/bootstrap-3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://victor-valencia.github.io/bootstrap-iconpicker/bootstrap-iconpicker/js/iconset/iconset-glyphicon.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://victor-valencia.github.io/bootstrap-iconpicker/bootstrap-iconpicker/js/iconset/iconset-all.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://victor-valencia.github.io/bootstrap-iconpicker/bootstrap-iconpicker/js/bootstrap-iconpicker.js"></script>

<button class="icon btn btn-default" data-iconset="glyphicon" data-icon="glyphicon-camera" role="iconpicker"></button>


<div id="click">Click here to change the icon</div>
```

Comment: I tested it, but it is not working. Does your code snippet work in your browser?

Comment: @Jarla my changes now update the `data-icon` attribute on the button, which is what your question asked for.

Comment: Ah ok, I see. I thought this would change the default selected icon. But it doesn't ;(

Comment: @Jarla it changes the icon when the `id='click'` div is clicked.  Is that not what you wanted?

Comment: Well no, when I test it I still see the icon `glyphicon-camera`

Comment: But in your image there is no visible icon, like here: http://victor-valencia.github.io/bootstrap-iconpicker/

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to select the icon with the data-icon property of `glyphicon-bomb`, then use:

```
$('.icon[data-icon="glyphicon-bomb"]').
```

*Edit*: Posted before I saw the edit.

Comment: I tested it exactly like you wrote, but it is still not working. Did you test it in a fiddle or code snippet?

Comment: I have edited my answer as I forgot to place wrapping quotes inside the round brackets.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a hard time with it, too. The `data-icon` thing was just not working (bug?)

That way it worked for me:

**Setting a glyph**

```
$("#buttonid").iconpicker("setIcon", "glyphicon-leaf");
```

**Remove current glyph**

```
$("#buttonid").iconpicker("setIcon", "glyphicon-");
```

You have to be careful not to forget the prefix `glyphicon-` - at least for the [Bootstrap glyphs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/)